# php - index array error using odbc_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, odbc

I have follow issue with my php function; it tell me that my sql fields not find instead they are present.
what mistake did I make in the code?
Thanks for any help
Andrea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e1gR.jpg)

```
function get_card($carta_posted) {
    global $connection;
    $query="SELECT f50carta, f50nome, f50cognome FROM qs36f.fid050f"; //where carta = '970002871875'";
    
    if($carta_posted != null) {
        //echo $_GET["card_id"];
        $query.=" WHERE f50carta = '".$carta_posted."' LIMIT 1";
    }   
    $response=array();
    $response["records"] = array();
    $result = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
     
    if (odbc_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row=odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
            $card_item = array(
                'carta' => $row['f50carta'],
                'nome' => $row['f50nome'],
                'cognome' => $row['f50cognome']
            );
            array_push($response["records"], $card_item);
        }
    } else {
        $response=("No Record Found"); 
    }
    echo json_encode($response); 
}

?>
```

**Notice**:  Undefined index: f50carta in **C:\xampp\htdocs\wstest\cards_post.php** on line **96**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: f50nome in **C:\xampp\htdocs\wstest\cards_post.php** on line **97**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: f50cognome in **C:\xampp\htdocs\wstest\cards_post.php** on line **98**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: could you pass the code as `code block`?

Comment: if(odbc_num_rows($result)>0){
  while($row=odbc_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $card_item = array(
    'carta' => $row['f50carta'],
    'nome' => $row['f50nome'],
    'cognome' => $row['f50cognome']
   );
   array_push($response["records"], $card_item);
  }
  } else {
   $response=("No Record Found");
  }

Comment: i've used an OCR to convert the image to text, please review if anything was not copied okay.

Comment: it's perfect (sorry is the first time I'm using Stack)

Comment: anyone could help me? maybe is the method to access array?

Comment: Reformatted code